# Azure AD - Custom Application Roles via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, rbac, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been playing with RBAC in Azure AD, in particular custom application roles.

It all works well, but is a bit manual, i.e. downloading, editing and uploading the manifest and then assigning each user/group to one of these roles via the management portal.

Is there a way to do that via powershell or even code, say the Graph API?

If not, I presume it's a planned feature, so does anyone know a the likely ETA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now this feature is not available via the AAD PowerShell Module, but it will find its way there eventually. We are working on releasing a new PowerShell module soon that sits atop ADAL which means we will soon be making cmdlets that directly target the Graph API.

For now, you can make direct queries using the Graph Client Library or pure REST calls. I believe an example of setting Application Roles should be available in this sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console

I hope this helps!
Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: Has this changed? Is it now available for PowerShell?

Comment: The new AAD PowerShell Module which works off of the AAD Graph API is available today here: [AAD PowerShell Module v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/azureactivedirectory). It should support this, however I have not personally tried it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Before you can use Windows PowerShell to manage RBAC, you must have the following:

Windows PowerShell, Version 3.0 or 4.0. To find the version of Windows PowerShell, type:$PSVersionTable and verify that the value of PSVersion is 3.0 or 4.0.

Azure PowerShell version 0.8.8 or later.

To get detailed help for any cmdlet that you see in this tutorial, use the Get-Help cmdlet.

```
Get-Help <cmdlet-name> -Detailed
```

For example, to get help for the Add-AzureAccount cmdlet, type:

```
Get-Help Add-AzureAccount -Detailed
```

Since RBAC only works with Azure Resource Manager, the first thing to do is to switch to Azure Resource Manager mode, type:

```
PS C:\> Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
```

Here is the complete tutorial on

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-powershell/

Comment: Perhaps I'm misundertanding something, but does that control Application Roles as described and configured here http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/? AFAIK, that isn't resource group based, at least I can't get any of those cmdlets to return the roles I've already defined in my dev tenant.